# Call to a member function format() on a non-object date format

Tags: php, html, date, time, formatdatetime

i've got this code, 
i don't know why when i run my file it says

Fatal error: Call to a member function format() on a non-object in /membri/bestparty/IOS/IOS/Scrittura_dati.php on line 26

here is the code

```
<?php
$festa = $_POST['festa'];
$data = $_POST['data'];
$luogo = $_POST['luogo'];
$prezzo = $_POST['prezzo'];
$prezzosp = $_POST['prezzosp'];
$lista = $_POST['nliste'];
$linkevento = $_POST['linkevento'];
$servbus = $_POST['servbus'];
$bottmin = $_POST['bottmin'];
$org = $_GET['org'];
$buynow = $_POST['buynow'];
if ($buynow == 'yes') {
    $buynow = 1;
}
else {
    $buynow = 0;
}
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', $data);
$date_out = $date->format('Y-m-d');
$data = $date_out;

$nomeimg = $festa;
$nomeimg = str_replace(' ', '_', $nomeimg);
```

Comment: Can we have `var_dump($_POST['data']);`?

Comment: createFromFormat returns a new DateTime instance or FALSE on failure, so you are calling format function on type that is not an instance of an object.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this part of code:

```php
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', $data);
if (!$date || $date->format('d-m-Y') != $data) {
    exit("Date '$data' is invalid or format is not 'd-m-Y'!");
}
$data = $date->format('Y-m-d');
```